# pass the signup instance to signin method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some classes like:

signin.h signin.m

signup.h signup.m

So in my signup.m i have one method. inside that method i need to call one method. When i added that inside my signup.m i am getting some server error some time getting crash.

So it is possible to call the method in my signin.m to signup.m

Here is my method name in my signin.m

```
- (void)signInmethods:(NSDictionary *)params {
    [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] showActivityControllerWithMessage:nil inController:self];

    [[PCWebServiceManager sharedWebServiceManager] signInWithParameters:params completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        self.signInBtn.enabled = YES;
//        [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] hideActivityIndicator];

        if (error) {
            [self forceLogout];

            [PCUtilities showAlertWithTitle:nil message:error.localizedDescription cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"];
            [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] hideActivityIndicator];

        }else {
            PCLoginObject *loginObject = (PCLoginObject *)responseObject;
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                [self performSelector:@selector(handleSignInResponse:) withObject:loginObject afterDelay:0.2];
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

I need to use this method in my signup.m inside this below code.

```
- (void)signUpWithname:(NSDictionary *)params {


    [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] showActivityControllerWithMessage:nil inController:self];

    [[PCWebServiceManager sharedWebServiceManager] signUpWithParameters:params completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
          [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] hideActivityIndicator];

            if((APP_DELEGATE.loginObject = (PCLoginObject*)result))
            {
            [PCSharedClass sharedInstance].userID =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)APP_DELEGATE.loginObject.userId];
            [self performSelector:@selector(showSignUpSuccess) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
        }
            else{

[self signInmethods:params];.. `self` is wrong i know that.


            }

    }];

    }
```

I get some idea in so so i added method name in in my signin.h :

```
@interface PCSignInVC : UIViewController

- (void)signUpWithname:(NSDictionary *)params;
@end
```

After that also still i am getting error in my signup.m method:

I need to use my signin.m method inside my signup.m.Help me out thanks!

I know that i should create a new class to contain these common methods that need to be used from each controller. Each controller can then instantiate this new class to use when required.

this warning comming and my activity indicator is not going off. still running

```
**Warning: Attempt to present PCModalActivityController: 0x7fe7f4100110  on PCSignUpTVC: 0x7fe7f1f4b230 which is already presenting (null)

 Warning: Attempt to present PCModalActivityController: 0x7fe7f4125be0  on PCSignUpTVC: 0x7fe7f1e5eda0 which is already presenting (null)**
```

But i am new to ios. Dont know how to create that class to use my method name.

Please help me.Thanks!

```
- (void)handleSignInResponse:(PCLoginObject *)loginObject {

    [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] hideActivityIndicator];

    if (loginObject.statusCode == eSuccess) {
        _userNameField.text = @"";
        _passwordField.text = @"";

        [PCSharedClass sharedInstance].userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)loginObject.userId];
        [PCSharedClass sharedInstance].userStatus = loginObject.facilityStatus;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:loginObject.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:loginObject.emialId forKey:@"emailId"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:loginObject.phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];

        APP_DELEGATE.loginObject = loginObject;

        switch (loginObject.facilityStatus) {
            case eUserIncompleteStatus: {
                //Redirect the user to About me screen.
                PCAboutMeVC *aboutMeVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PCAboutMeVC"];
                aboutMeVC.firstSignUp = YES;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutMeVC animated:YES];

                break;
            }

            case eUserInactiveStatus: {
                //Message, confirm and cancel button
                break;
            }

            case eUserActiveStatus:
            case eUserLoggedOffStatus: {
                //Go to home screen
                KYDrawerController *drawerController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KYDrawerController"];
                [self presentViewController:drawerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                APP_DELEGATE.drawerController = drawerController;

                break;
            }

            case eUserPendingStatus: {
                UIAlertView *dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                                 message: @"You can not access your account untill we will verify your facility details. Thank you."
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                                       otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
                [dialog show];

                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }

    }else {
        [PCUtilities showAlertWithTitle:nil message:loginObject.failurereason cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"];
    }


    //Enable the signIn Button
    self.signInBtn.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: whats error u get **am getting some server error some time getting crash**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  it like warning after that my my activity indicator is still running not getting off

Comment: Isn't this like the 3rd time you've asked this same question?

Comment: but still i am not getting any solution i have tried but still that warning arrives

Comment: can you show your method **handleSignInResponse**

Comment: inside my `signupwithnames` only i am using that `handle response` so first i need to use `signupwithnames`  inside my `signinmethod ` in my signin.m

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  i have updated

Comment: @PhillipMills  i have explained all inside my post...

Comment: actualy what i need is i explined in my post. i need to use one method in signin.m to my signup.m...if that not match with my title i will change the title.please give some solution for my post,thanks

Comment: means that should i need to add some more code ?? to get my solution??

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik   can u please help me to solve this